# Web Site crashing Iphone Safari

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, safari

I have a site that all of a sudden crashes safari on my iPhone every singe time I go to it. It worked fine earlier in the day and the only thing I did was clean up the html and CSS It works fine in my Ipad and desktop safari.

Just wondering if anyone had any ideas on what it could be or if they could test it out on their iPhones.

http://svmadvancedcleaning.com/

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the source, and you are getting a JavaScript error that may be contributing to the issue. The error is because you are calling a jQuery function before jQuery is loaded.

Take a look at the page that loads in your iframe, you'll see this in the page source header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/active.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

active.js should be below jquery.min.js to prevent that particular error. This may not be the cause of the Safari crash, but it should be fixed and it may be a contributing factor.